# MLE estimate for least squares if features have Gaussian noise

Tags: maximum-likelihood, least-squares, error

We have come across the problem of MLE estimate for least squares if errors are normally distributed, eg, $Y_i=\beta x_i+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^2)$. The estimate for the above case is very well known. But what if we have gaussian noise in the features themselves, or  $Y_i=\beta( x_i+\epsilon)$, where $\epsilon$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^2)$. Will we get the same MLE estimate for the $\beta$ coefficients?

---

My solution: No, the estimates would vary, from the second case, we can derive,
 $\epsilon$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^2)$,
 or $(Y_i-\beta x_i)/\beta$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^2)$
and after equating the log likelihood to zero, we get a different answer. Is my approach correct?

Comment: It seems to me that you must improve the quality of the question before it is answerable. The notation for your second $Y_i$ seems wrong. Shouldn't this be $Y_i=\beta(x_i+\epsilon_1)+\epsilon_2$, with $\epsilon_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_i^2)$? Also, which estimates are you asking about? Estimates for the coefficients $\beta$ or all parameters (so also $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$)? I completely don't understand the description of your solution. Instead of least squared, I think you want to say linear regression.

Comment: I meant the $\beta$ coefficients and I want the estimates for linear regression

Comment: Single $\epsilon$ shared by all $Y_i$? or each individual $i$ has its $\epsilon_i$? It is totally different.

Comment: For $\beta\ne 0$ your second model is merely a reparameterization of the first, whence the MLE will not change.  When $\beta=0$ your second model drops some of the possibilities permitted by the first one because it requires $Y$ to be identically zero.

Comment: @whuber can you please elaborate the reparametrization part in a separate answer. I have just started learning these concepts and would greatly appreciate if you expanded your answer a bit. Directing me to an appropriate resource will also work fine.

Comment: I would suggest consulting your favorite introductory account of MLE, because the underlying concept is basic: namely, that it doesn't matter how you express the variables in a minimization problem, because the objective function still attains the same minima at the same locations.  This means that the MLE of a re-expressed parameter is just the re-expression of that parameter.  In the present case your second model merely uses $\beta\sigma$ in place of $\sigma.$  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=maximum+likelihood+invariant for references to this property.

Comment: @whuber if $\epsilon_i$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^2)$  then 
$Y_i=\alpha+\beta(x_i+\epsilon_i) = \alpha+\beta x_i+\beta \epsilon_i$ or   
$E(Y_i)=\alpha + \beta x_i + \beta E(\epsilon_i$)$ = \alpha +\beta x_i$  or
$Var(Y_i)=Var(\alpha + \beta x_i) + Var(\beta \epsilon_i) = \beta^2 Var(\epsilon_i) = \beta^2 \sigma^2$  
So $Y_i$ ~ $N(\alpha + \beta x_i, \beta^2 \sigma^2)$ but commonly for linear regression, $Y_i$ ~ $N(\alpha + \beta x_i, \sigma^2)$. So the new distribution for $Y_i$ will it affect the MLE?

Comment: That's a good analysis.  The answer is that the MLE will produce three estimates $\hat\alpha,\hat\beta,$ and $\hat{\beta^2\sigma^2}.$  From these you can recover the ML estimate $\hat\sigma^2 = \hat{\beta^2\sigma^2}/(\hat\beta)^2$ assuming $\hat\beta\ne 0.$